# How to process time functions in awk in flow

Tags: awk

There is file `test.txt`

```
ABCDEF 2019-09-16 02:45:49
ABCDEF 2019-09-16 02:26:27
ABCDEF 2019-09-16 02:15:23
```

Need answer as with Unix time:

```
ABCDEF 1568583949
ABCDEF 1568582787
ABCDEF 1568582123
```

I'm using this AWK code.

```
cat test.txt|sed 's/[-:]/ /g'|awk '{print $1, mktime("$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7")}'
```

But I've got wrong answer. How can I fix it?

```
ABCDEF -1
ABCDEF -1
ABCDEF -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easy to do a single `gsub()` on the combined record containing both the 2nd the 3rd columns as below. Since the first argument of `gsub()` takes a regular expression argument you can provide both the de-limit characters and insist them to be replaced by a single white-space (default value of `FS`).

```
awk '{ var = ($2 FS $3); gsub(/[-:]/, FS, var); print $1, mktime(var) }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{val=$2;val2=$3;gsub(/-/," ",val);gsub(/:/," ",val2);print $1,mktime(val OFS val2)}' Input_file
```

OR(without using variables for `$2` or `$3` try:

```
awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2);gsub(/:/," ",$3);print $1,mktime($2 OFS $3)}' Input_file
```

***Generic solution:*** If you don't want to hard code fields for date and time then try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/:|-/," ",val)
  print $1,mktime(val)
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

***Fixing OP's attempt:*** Though this shold be done with single `awk` etc just fixing your code here.

```
sed 's/[-:]/ /g' Input_file |awk '{print $1, mktime($2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7)}'
```

***From `man awk` about `mktime`:***

> mktime(datespec)   Turn datespec into a time stamp of the same form as
>   returned by systime(), and return the result.  The datespec is a
>   string of the form YYYY MM DD HH  MM  SS[ DST].  The contents of the
>   string are six or seven numbers representing respectively the full
>   year including century, the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month
>   from 1 to 31, the hour of the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0 to
>   59, the second from 0 to 60, and an optional day-light  saving flag. 
>   The values of these numbers need not be within the ranges specified;
>   for example, an hour of -1 means 1 hour before midnight. The
>   origin-zero Gregorian calendar is assumed, with year 0 preceding year
>   1 and year -1 preceding year 0.  The time is assumed to be in the 
>   local            timezone.   If  the  daylight saving flag is
>   positive, the time is assumed to be daylight saving time; if zero, the
>   time is assumed to be standard time; and if negative (the default),
>   mktime() attempts to determine whether daylight saving time is in
>   effect for the specified time.  If datespec does not contain enough
>   elements or if the resulting time is out of range, mktime() returns
>   -1.

Comment: Thaks a lot for detail explanation!

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Give it sometime and you can select anyone answer as correct one out of all. Cheers and happy learning on this great site.